# Probability of selecting in a firm

Tags: probability

**I can't understand what's wrong in my solution**

[image]

My solution:-

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem like you took into account that "the probability of at least one of his applications being rejected is $0.6$" anywhere in your work.

Comment: Yeah, and my my method the probability of at least one of his applications being rejected comes out to be "0.65" not "0.6"

Comment: Do you know what the actual answer is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming $X,Y$ are independent from one another which is not given.

What you are given:

$$P(X)=0.7, P(Y')=0.5 = P(Y), P(X'+Y')=0.6$$

What you want to find:

$$P(X+Y)=...$$

From here, use

$$P(X+Y)=P(X)+P(Y)-P(XY)$$
$$=P(X)+P(Y)-(1-P(X'+Y'))$$

The last equality is one of DeMorgan's laws.

Comment: Isn't it $P(Y')=0.5$ as one of the given?

Comment: Yes, so technically derived. They are the same.

Comment: If P(Y')=0.5 this implies P(Y) is also 0.5

Comment: Yes, your deductions on $P(X'),P(Y')$ were correct, just not their independence.

Comment: @DavidP so I can use my approach only when it's given that two events are "independent" right? Is there any way to judge if the events are dependent or not (if in question it is not stated)?

Comment: Always assume events are dependent unless stated or otherwise obvious, like if $X$ was the event of flipping a coin and $Y$ was the event of rolling a die. In real life firms $X$ and $Y$ may or may not be independent, they can be owned by the same parent company or have some other communication.